# How to input polynomial in manipulate

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there any way how to input polynomial in manipulate in Wolfram Mathematica?

I try this:

```
Manipulate[Plot[a, {x, -6, 6}, ImageSize -> 400],{{a, -3 x - 2 x^2 + x^3, "Polynomial"}}]
```

It's working if i don't save it in cdf format. Does anyone know how to fix it so it will work when i save it in cdf format?

Comment: maybe use a string and `ToExpression`  (I don't have cdfplayer to try it).  Of course there are security issues letting a user eval arbitrary strings (may be why your code doesn't work with cdfplayer )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this will do

```
Manipulate[ Plot[#, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> #
    ] &@Total@
   MapIndexed[# x^(First@#2 - 1) &, coef ], {{coef, {0, 1}}}]
```

[image]